# Different display & value for input box garnished with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a input field with ngx-bootstrap.
Here is the view code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="blindStructure" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Blind Structure</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input [(ngModel)]="selected" formControlName='blindStructure'
       placeholder="Search The Blind Structure" [typeahead]="blinds" autocomplete="off"
       [typeaheadMinLength]="0" [optionsListTemplate]="customListTemplate" 
       class="form-control blind">
       <span title="Search" class="btn search-img"></span>
    <ng-template #customListTemplate let-matches="matches" let-query="query"
        let-typeaheadTemplateMethods>
        <ul class="fix-create" [class.dropdown-menu]="isBs3">
           <li class="custom-list-group-item">
           <span title="Search" class="btn add-img"></span>
           <button class="btn default create-btn" (click)="openModal(blindStructure, 2)"> 
           Create New Blind Structure</button></li>
         </ul>
          <ul class="custom-list-group" [class.dropdown-menu]="isBs3">
               <li class="custom-list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items- 
                          center"
                   *ngFor="let match of matches" 
                   [class.active]="typeaheadTemplateMethods.isActive(match)"
                   (click)="typeaheadTemplateMethods.selectMatch(match, $event)"
                   (mouseenter)="typeaheadTemplateMethods.selectActive(match)">
                  {{ match.item }}
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm"
                                 (click)="openModal(blindStructure, 1)">View</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </ng-template>
</div>
```

The "blinds" is defined and populated in component file in ngOnInit:

```
export class MtctTemplateCreationComponent implements OnInit {
    blinds: string[];
    constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private blindStructureService : BlindStructureDataService,
    private modalService: BsModalService
    ) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.blindStructureService.getBlindStructures().subscribe(response =>{
    this.blinds = response.body["responseObject"].map(el => el.name );
});
```

This results in
[image]

The resultObject had 2 properties name & blindId. As I click the save button(which is partly hidden in the image), it is the name of the blind structure which is getting submitted. But I want name of the blind structure to be displayed, but blindId to be submitted. I can make the id to be displayed & then all my problems will be gone, but it will be hard for the user to understand

**Edit** I tried to make "blinds" as object array in place of string by introducing an interface:

```
export interface Opt {
    blindId: number;
    name: string;
}
```

In the component file declaring blinds as Opt array:

```
blinds: Opt[] ;
ngOnInit(): void {
         
   this.blindStructureService.getBlindStructures().subscribe(response => 
   {
            this.blinds = response.body["responseObject"];
            
   });
```

And in the template file:

> {{ match.item.name }}

in place of

> {{ match.item}}

But it does not solve my problem.
Compare this with an select dropdown in the same page:

```
<select class="form-control {{submit && 
    mtctTemplateForm.controls['gameTypeId'].errors && 
    mtctTemplateForm.controls['gameTypeId'].errors.required ? 'required- 
             highlight' : ''}}"
    id="gameType" formControlName='gameTypeId' name='gameTypeId'
                        
    (change)="onChangeGameType($event.target.value)">
    <option [ngValue]=null>Select any Game types</option>
    <option *ngFor="let list of gameTypes" [value]="list.gameTypeId"> 
           {{list.typeName}}</option>
</select>
```

Here we are selecting a game type which is a string (Texas Holdem, Omaha etc.) but a numeric value 1,2 etc. is getting submitted.

Comment: Can you make small working demo ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, I decided to go for a map which will have blind.name as key & blind.blindId as value & populate the same in ngOnInit. And at the time of submitting the form, added the blindId. That was I was able to solve the problem. Thanks for showing interest.